# Hot to auto-generate TWO unique identifiers for an association table in SQL 2008's Design view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using the shortcut, via properties. When i only need to generate one identifier, i set "(Is) identity" to "Yes", but i can't seem to do it for two rows. Please Help.

Answer (score 3):

no possible with anything that is built in, you will have to roll your own with triggers but with that comes locking and concurrency....don't do it

Comment: He could do a calculated column that is the autoincrement `PK * -1` - but I question the motive.

Answer (score 2):

A table can only have one identity column.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need two identifiers for one record?

Identifiers in an association table should be foreign keys to the identity values in the related tables, not autogenerated themselves, although you may have a single additional autogenerated identity key in the association table as well.